# Route Message from JMS queue1 to queue2 unchanged using Camel

Tags: apache-camel, jms

When I consume a JMS message from queue1 and simply send it to queue2 the message that has landed on queue 2 has:

1. the messageId on the original message now populated in the breadcrumbId header.
2. a new messageId.

Can I just transfer the message unchanged, thus keeping the messageId the same?

I've tried `forceSendOriginalMessage=true` (and also `mapJmsMessage=false`) as below but this made no difference.

```java
from("cMQConnectionFactory1:queue:queue1?forceSendOriginalMessage=true")
.to("cMQConnectionFactory1:queue:queue2")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't keep JMSMessageID the same. As per [specs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/apirefs.1111/e13943/WebLogic.Messaging.IMessage.JMSMessageID.html), it is JMS provider-specific.

> When a message is sent, JMSMessageID can be ignored. When the Send or
>   Publish method returns, it contains a provider-assigned value.

The parameter `forceSendOriginalMessage` allows you to send the original message, not a copy of it.

Comment: It seems a shame this behaviour is fixed. I have 2 routes sending to the same direct: endpoint. Messages from one route have the messageId I want in the actual messageId field, messages from the other have the messageId I want in the breadcrumbId. I'd hoped I didn't need to check for the existence of a breadcrumbid but will have to....